# CPLEX how to sum with some constraint

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

There is a 2D array implying working machine number and its processing time like below.
Also, an array named L implying which machine that I want to sum.

```
arr = [
[1, 10],
[2, 20],
[3, 15],
[4, 10]
]

L= [1,4]
```

Can I add a constraint that sum all the processing time of machine appearing in the L array?

For this problem, I want to sum 10+10 because 1 and 4 is in L.

Answer (score 1):

```
range r2=1..2;
range r4=1..4;

int arr[r4,r2] = [
[1, 10],
[2, 20],
[3, 15],
[4, 10]
];

int L[r2]= [1,4];

int s=sum(k in r2) sum(i in r4:arr[i][1]==L[k]) arr[i][2];

execute
{
writeln(s);
}
```

gives

20

and if you want to be able to address as many machines as possible you could write

```
range r2=1..2;
range r4=1..4;

int arr[r4,r2] = [
[1, 10],
[2, 20],
[3, 15],
[4, 10]
];

{int} L={1,4};

int s=sum(k in L) sum(i in r4:arr[i][1]==k) arr[i][2];

execute
{
writeln(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still have another question. How about if I want to formulate a tuple L instead of an array L, and I don't know the range of r2, which means that I don't know how many machine numbers in the tuple. In this case, how to sum the time like this?Thank you